# tkinter issue can't close the GUI with the X button top RHS

Tags: tkinter

i can create a GUI using python and tkinter, but if i try to close the GUI by pressing the X in the top right corner it does nothing, it doesn't respond. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I deleted python, and then reinstalled, but still same issue, I tried rolling back to a previous version of python, but no luck either.

Comment: Is this more than just a simple GUI app?  Which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the closing event and define an action for it. Use the protocol method to handle the window close event,

```html
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy) # Destroy the window


# The main loop
root.mainloop()
```